# Integrating the code generated from simulink in the project

Tags: code-generation, simulink

I have a simulink model and I generate the code using simulink coder for Generic Real-Time target.
I then copy the generated files (*.c and *.h) into my project in MPLAB. 
Here I have the main.c file and here I use MdlStart() for initializing the model one time and then in infinite loop I use MdlOutputs() and MdlUpdate() for running the model. Everything works fine.

Now actually I want to speed the execution of the model and therefore I want to split my model into sub-systems and execute the sub-system only when required (e.g. I want to execute some sub-systems everytime and some only every few ms instead of everytime). I could split the model into subsystems and also made every sub-system atomic so that I get the different function for every sub-system. Now these different sub-system's functions are called from MdlOutputs() and MdlUpdate(). So they execute everytime the model is executed.

Actually I want to use some timer in my MPLAB project and then execute few sub-systems lets say at every 100ms. I also do not want to modify the auto-generated *.c and *.h files.

So instead of executing these sub-system's functions everytime through MdlOutputs() and MdlUpdate(), Is it possible to call the sub-system's functions from my main.c file without touching the auto-generated *.c and *.h files?

I hope that I have explained it well.

waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to model everything you are trying to do with subsystems inside Simulink. For example, you can use "Enabled subsystems" or "Triggered subsystems" to create subsystems which run only on some time steps. I am not sure what kind of timer you are referring to. If it is Simulink time then you would need to run different subsystems at different sample rates which would give you a multirate model. If your timer is just another external source, then try triggered or enabled subsystems. That is the best way to avoid modifying generated files.

Doc for these subsystems are at http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/conditional-subsystems-1.html.

Comment: Multirate is the way to go. The generated step function has integrated counters to call the right functions in each step.